# java :loop user inputs individually

Tags: java

I have a program which tells the user to input three `ints` and  converts each one to a string. *I.e 1 = one ; ...etc*. The problem here is defining the `ints` for every user input. How can i get it with just one input and loop it to take another, considering to separate inputs so we can use it individually in every phrase down here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] i = { "zero" , "one" , "two" , "three" , "four" , 
                    "five", "six", "seven" , "eight" , "nine" , "ten" };

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("I have ..... Networking books, ..... Database books, and ..... Programming books. ");

    String text = "" , text1 = "", text2 = "" ;    
    // loop i/p and using it in every phrase seperatellty 

    for (int a = 1; a <= 1; a++) {
        int word = in.nextInt();
        int word1 = in.nextInt();
        int word2 = in.nextInt();

        text = i[word];
        text1 = i[word1]; 
        text2 = i[word2]; 
    }

    System.out.println("I have " + text + " Networking books, "
                                        + text1 + "  Database books, and " 
                                        + text2 +" Programming books. ");

}}
```

Comment: Why do you want to loop??

Comment: it just an assignment tells me to do !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are trying to do

Note:

You have missed range check for the entered no. This will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`if you are trying to access the array `i` for indices above 10

```
import java.util.*;
class UserInputReader {

    private static final int EXPECTED_NUM_COUNT = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] i = { "zero" , "one" , "two" , "three" , "four" , 
                    "five", "six", "seven" , "eight" , "nine" , "ten" };

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);   
        String[] words = new String[EXPECTED_NUM_COUNT];

        int numCount = 0;
        while(numCount < 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter the number");
            int num = in.nextInt();
            if (num >= 0 && num <= 10) {
                words[numCount] = i[num];
                numCount++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enter no is invalid. Try again entering a number between 0 - 10");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Entered nums " + Arrays.toString(words));

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, no problem and welcome. Glad that I could help.

Comment: this is what i wanted instead of define int for every input , just make it array and use it,s element to compare , thanks :D  {         System.out.println("I have "+ words[0]+ " Networking books," + words[1] +" Database books, and "+words[2]+ " Programming books.") ;